# How to retrieve data from a website into an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

I am making an iPhone application. I am a beginner.

I want to fetch the data from my website. What should I do to implement this?

Comment: what data do you want to fetch exactly? There are many different ways to pull data from a webserver but it depends on what type of data.

Comment: I want to retrive the text(sentences ) from website's database Thanks

Comment: @Julia see my revised answer on a good jumping off point for writing mobile apps.

Comment: Ask your questions to the point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is getting data from website to iphone then you can just use JSON Parsing to get data.

Just you have to pass all the data as JSON string in iPhone from your website. And then parse the data once received into your iPhone.

Here you can refer to this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: @Coulton: Thanks for letting me know that link is non functional. Probably I am very late in updating this link. But better late than never :)

Answer (score 0):

For the server side, I suggest using a web service to send the data to your client.

**ORIGINAL AUTHOR'S REVISION:**

The September issue of Linux Journal has an excellent article on writing mobile apps that work for Android AND iPhone/iPad using free tools and frameworks. Here is a link to the article online:

[Developing Portable Mobile Web Applications](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10789)

Comment: hey but how can we implement that webservice. I am totally new. So please giude further. Thanks.

Comment: oww.... if so, I think that you just need simply wirte a web page and then use NSURLConnection to access the page, in this way , you can got the web page content , also the data if you want response to your iPhone app .

Comment: @Julia, please see my revised answer for this question. Linux Journal continues to be an invaluable resource to me as new technologies evolve. The referenced article is a must-read.

Answer (score 0):

Expose your data from your site as WebService, XML, JSON etc. Consume that using iPhone app.
Which language is being used your site?depending on that some sample could be provided.

Chapter 10 of James Kennard, Mastering Joomla! 1.5 : APIs and Webservices contains 8 pages about XML-RPC.

For real-live examples, search the Joomla! Extension Directory.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/xml-rpc

Here is another one to kick-start http://www.slideshare.net/coolparth/rest-api-for-joomla

Comment: Hey thanks but i am new to these things. Can you please give me detailed information or a tutorial?

Comment: @Julia What is your server side language? Java/PHP/Ruby/c# etc?

Comment: server side language is C#.net and CMS is Joomla. What should I do?

Comment: @Julia as per my knowledge Joomla CMS uses PHP not C#

Comment: Oops Sorry yeah it is Joomla and Php. My Bad

Comment: @ Julia Chapter 10 of James Kennard, Mastering Joomla! 1.5 : APIs and Webservices contains 8 pages about XML-RPC.

For real-live examples, search the Joomla! Extension Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will be using the NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest and NSURL classes here is an example from Apple; http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers suggest using NSURLConnection, but I find it to be a bit cumbersome to use on its own. I suggest using something that wraps NSURLConnection (or CFNetwork). Some examples: [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) (CFNetwork-based), [httpriot](http://labratrevenge.com/httpriot/docs/) and [Seriously](https://github.com/probablycorey/seriously) (NSURLConnection/block-based).