# Getting only desired data from the web

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on web base application in ios.I want to get only the desired data from the web .
for e.g. If there is a site which showing the information of train code , train schedule, seat availability i want to get the data related to only seat availability from that web page and render it to my own table. Is it really possible ?

Comment: it is only possible if you request particular data and u get that response(data) and u can fill that data to your requirment

Comment: This link will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295506/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-website-into-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

*I am not an iOS developer, so I can't give you code on how to do it.*

You'll be needing an HTML parser. The process is commonly called web/screen scraping. Have a read at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541965/459338

Comment: Is all html parser applicable for all sites

Comment: Well, technically, yes. Web pages are constructed via HTML. But there are several limitations. Flash sites, and Client-side dynamic web pages (Pages generated by JavaScript, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HTML Parser or use Regex to extract the pattern of the data that you want from the given url . However try to check whether the data provided by the website is copyrighted or not else you cannot use their data publicly via another interface without their permission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. For doing this you will be using the method of Parsing . Depending on the type of API you are getting whether it is JSON, XML or HTML etc , you can parse the desired data accordingly. You can check for the API's on the web for the type of information you would want to parse. Otherwise the database option is always there.